# How to set value inside div in JS

Tags: javascript

I have some code that looks like this:

```
document.getElementById("error").style.display = 'block';
```

and when this happens I also want to display the error that is supposed to be shown which is stored in another JS variable.  How can I add the value of that variable to the div which has id="error"

Thanks!

Comment: `.textContent` or `.innerHTML` or `.appendChild` + `document.createTextNode`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
var errorMsg = "<p>Example error message</p>"
document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = errorMsg
```

Answer (score 5):

```
document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = errMsg;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = my_js_variable;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var displayDiv = document.getElementById('error');
displayDiv.style.display = 'block';
displayDiv.innerHTML = yourVariable;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var errorDiv = document.getElementById("error");
errorDiv.innerHTML = yourVariable;
errorDiv.style.display = 'block';
```

Answer (score 2):

document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = variable

(using jQuery would be easier.