# How to Print javascript foreach values in Innerhtml

Tags: javascript, html

I'm fetching the datas from API using object.values Method and iterating with forEach. How can i print the values that are inside the foreach to my html div.

```js
const api_url = "https://api.wazirx.com/api/v2/tickers";

async function getapi(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  var data = await response.json();
  //Need to print this result in the result div
  Object.values(data.btcinr).forEach(val => console.log(val));
}

getapi(api_url);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Here is my JsFiddle :[Jsfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/JOHN_748/894sk6uy/5/)

Comment: By "print" do you mean to append them to that element or to actually print them on a printer?

Comment: No i mean appending the result to my div which has id as "result"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310787/how-to-set-value-inside-div-in-js/6310816 get current value from div and then provide it with `\`${oldvalue}, ${val}\``

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set value inside div in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310787/how-to-set-value-inside-div-in-js)

Comment: I've tried this but its not working its shows blank. Can u pls correct my jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `Object.values(data.btcinr)` returns array of string, then it should be something like this:

```
    var result = document.querySelector("#result")

    Object.values(data.btcinr).forEach(val => {
        const div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = val;
        result.appendChild(div);
    });
```

```js
["item1", "item2", "item3"].forEach(val => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = val;
    result.appendChild(div);
});
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only hit the DOM once for performance, here I use an array of the values and then append that.

You can decide if you want to wrap it or not - I commented out a wrap example.

```js
var html = [];
["<div>hi</div>", "I am the one", "I am not the one"].forEach(newhtml => {
  //html.push('<div>' + newhtml + '</div>');
  html.push(newhtml);
});
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = html.join('');
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Different way to wrap

```js
var html = ['<div>'];
["<div>hi</div>", "I am the one", "I am not the one"].forEach(newhtml => {
  //html.push('<div>' + newhtml + '</div>');
  html.push(newhtml);
});

// join and append final close
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = html.join('</div><div>') + '</div>';
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```